# Why I can't use helper in textbox placeholder tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I try to use Kentico CMS helper in textbox placeholder tag in ASP.NET but it doesn't work. When I tried to compile it I obtained error:"The name txtPassword does not exist in current context".

Could you explain why I can't use it that way? How can I do it?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="'<%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("Account.Password") %>'" AutoCompleteType="None"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on a data bind control context try with this

```
placeholder='<%# CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("Account.Password") %>'
```

Notice I've removed the outer `"`

if you're not on a data bind context, replace `#` by `=`

```
placeholder='<%= CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("Account.Password") %>'
```